# Randomly assign different names to each Table Cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

So I have a program which randomly assigns a name to each cell in the first row of my table from a list of names in a text box with the click of a button, what I want to do is assign different names to each of the cells in the textbox in the click of a button so that no two cells have the same name, here is my code so far:

```js
var rnd = function() {
  var things;
  things = document.getElementById('things').value;
  things = things.replace(', ', ',');
  things = things.split(',');
  setTimeout(function() {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll('.js-result');

    for (var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
      var thing = Math.floor(Math.random() * things.length);
      list.item(index).innerHTML = things[thing];
    }
  }, 500);
};
```

```css
fieldset input {
  display: block;
}
.result {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 75%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Black</th>
      <th>Blue</th>
      <th>B &amp; B</th>
      <th>Gold</th>
      <th>Green</th>
      <th>Gryphons</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form method="get" action="/" onsubmit="return false;">
          <fieldset>
            <label>
              <textarea style="width: 400px;height: 35px;" name="things" id="things">Forrest Gump, Tim Thomas, Pamila Henryson, Lotus Hobbes, Jerry Sparks, Kenneth Ingham</textarea>
            </label>
          </fieldset>
          <p>
            <input type="button" value="Pick one!" onclick="rnd();">
          </p>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="js-result result"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="js-result result"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="js-result result"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="js-result result"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="js-result result"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="js-result result"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of *accessing* the array element you can very well *mutate it* using `things.splice(thing,1)` - see demo below:

```js
var rnd = function() {
  var things;
  things = document.getElementById('things').value;
  things = things.replace(', ', ',');
  things = things.split(',');
  setTimeout(function() {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll('.js-result');

    for (var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
      var thing = Math.floor(Math.random() * things.length);
      list.item(index).innerHTML = things.splice(thing,1);
    }
  }, 500);
};
```

```css
fieldset input {
  display: block;
}
.result {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 75%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table align="center">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Black</th>
      <th>Blue</th>
      <th>B &amp; B</th>
      <th>Gold</th>
      <th>Green</th>
      <th>Gryphons</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form method="get" action="/" onsubmit="return false;">
          <fieldset>
            <label>
              <textarea style="width: 400px;height: 35px;" name="things" id="things">Forrest Gump, Tim Thomas, Pamila Henryson, Lotus Hobbes, Jerry Sparks, Kenneth Ingham</textarea>
            </label>
          </fieldset>
          <p>
            <input type="button" value="Pick one!" onclick="rnd();">
          </p>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="js-result result"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="js-result result"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="js-result result"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="js-result result"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="js-result result"></div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="js-result result"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is using the unique `things` array. This can be done by using the `filter` function on the array and passing in a predicate which checks for the uniqueness.

`let uniqueThings = things.filter((currentValue, index, array) => array.indexOf(currentValue) === index); ;

list.item(index).innerHTML = uniqueThings[index];`

**Complete Code:**

```js
var rnd = function () {
  var things;
  things = document.getElementById('things').value;
  things = things.replace(', ', ',');
  things = things.split(',');
  setTimeout(function () {
            var list = document.querySelectorAll('.js-result');
    
            for (var index = 0; index < list.length; index++) {
                var thing = Math.floor(Math.random() * things.length);
              let uniqueThings = things.filter((currentValue, index, array) => array.indexOf(currentValue) === index); ;   
              list.item(index).innerHTML = uniqueThings[index];
            }
  }, 500);
 };
```

```css
margin: 1em 0;
 }

 table {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 75%;
 }
 td,
 th {
     border: 1px solid #dddddd;
     text-align: left;
     padding: 8px;
     text-align: center
 }
 tr:nth-child(even) {
     background-color: #dddddd;
 }
```

```html
<table align="center">
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th>
<th>Black</th>
<th>Blue</th>
<th>B &amp; B</th>
<th>Gold</th>
<th>Green</th>
<th>Gryphons</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
 <form method="get" action="/" onsubmit="return false;">
  <fieldset>
   <label>
    <textarea style="width: 400px;height: 35px;" name="things" id="things">Forrest Gump, Tim Thomas, Pamila Henryson, Lotus Hobbes, Jerry Sparks, Kenneth Ingham</textarea>
   </label>
  </fieldset>
  <p>
   <input type="button" value="Pick one!" onclick="rnd();">
  </p>
 </form>
</td>
<td><div class="js-result result"></div></td>
<td><div class="js-result result"></div></td>
<td><div class="js-result result"></div></td>
<td><div class="js-result result"></div></td>
<td><div class="js-result result"></div></td>
<td><div class="js-result result"></div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```